# Get total sum from 2 columns in different tables

Tags: mysql

I need to get the total result of costs from 2 small companies that are part of the same owner.

The costs tables for the 2 companies are in the same database.

I will explain it better with a picture[image]

What I need to get is the final total (as explained in the picture).

I can do it making 2 separate queries and then making sum the variables, but I want to know if is possible to get the total result making **one** query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(neto_amount) FROM fincost1) + (SELECT SUM(neto_amount) FROM fincost2) 
FROM dual
```

Comment: The DUAL is special one row, one column table present by default in  databases. If you can run function without use specific table - use dual, because you can't run select without FROM. Chceck the link: http://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-dual-table.php

Comment: thanks for the helpful info. You may want to add it on the answer itself :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select  sum(total) from (
SELECT SUM(column_name)  as total FROM table_name1
union all
SELECT SUM(column_name) as total  FROM table_name2
) as alias
```

Answer (score 0):

I can understand why you have parallel tables for costs -- because they are simpler in terms of security and access rights.  However, from almost every other perspective (maintenance, querying, backup/restore), it is better to have a single table with a column indicating the "owner" and/or "company".

You can do what you want using subqueries.  I prefer to put them in the `from` clause:

```
select (amount1 + amount2) as neto_neto_amount
from (select sum(neto_amount) as amount1 from fin_costs_1) t1 cross join
     (select sum(neto_amount) as amount2 from fin_costs_2) t2 ;
```

Comment: trying to use your query but getting this error `Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @Sisir . . . I have a way of leaving those out when using a subquery that returns one row.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using [UNIONS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT sum(u.cost)
FROM (
   SELECT sum(neto_amount) cost
   FROM fin_costs1
   UNION
   SELECT sum(neto_amount) cost
   FROM fin_costs2
) u
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are some other ways of doing this but the way I do this is like this:

I get the SUMs of two tables in two different sql SUM functions like:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name1;


SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name2;
```

and simply add the together like `$sum1 + $sum2 = $total;`

and the `echo $totalsum;`

done